# How to add XML Attribute and value to [XMLElement] class property?

Tags: c#, xml

In C#, I have this class:

```
    public class LightHouseTicketForXML {
        [XmlElement( "assigned-user-id")]
        public string assignedUserId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement( "body" )]
        public string body { get; set; }

        [XmlElement( "milestone-id" )]
        public string milestoneId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement( "state" )]
        public string state { get; set; }

        [XmlElement( "title" )]
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to give the assigned-user-id the attribute and value type="integer". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use xsd.exe (Visual Studio Tools), you'll get some clues.  (However, the naming conventions produced by it are terrible).
It will create another class for that element, [XMLAttribute] over a public int type; and then include that class in the class above.